# Azure Queues dequeue count growing with Rebus core

Tags: deque, .net-core-3.1, azure-queues, rebus

I am using Rebus (https://github.com/rebus-org (v.5.3.1)) and until now everything has worked out just fine for years. (we upgraded from core 2.0 to 3.1 a couple of weeks ago)

For the last couple of days, it had a lot of messages that just grows in the "dequeue count" column. we use Azure storage queue. The que handles the other messages as it should, but we still got 6000+ message with dequeue count higher than 250 in this moment.

I can’t really find anything that looks off, and it doesn’t add any rows in the error que.

I have tried to restart the server, so the Rebus is totally restarted but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an underlying function that throws exception. And it seems like rebus swallow it somewhere.
in my rebus job i changed to just “return” and not doing anything. the que started to disappear.

I still don’t know why rebus not stopped trying after 5(in my case) try and added to error que